# mlr package installation error

Tags: r, install.packages, mlr

When I try to install `mlr` package, I get this error message

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>   ‘mlr’
>   These will not be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue happened once to me, if I remember right, you need `Rtools` as others have said. Notice, though, `Rtools` is not a package, it's an official maintained package-building application.

You must download it from the release page: [Building R for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Comment: I tried to install mlr package and nothing went wrong. So I guess, it was only an actualization problem with the mlr package to be compatible with R 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
install.packages('mlr', repo='http://cran.fiocruz.br/')
```

Use the same link as mentioned above by Koba. But when you will be asked a question like "Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?"
Type "n".

And then you can use the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with the cran mirror that you are using . You can try picking one of the mirrors from https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html and install the package from a specific repo .

Example :

```
install.packages('mlr', repo='http://cran.fiocruz.br/')
```

The full list of repos can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html . You can try picking a few repos to see which one works .

Comment: I tried that way, but that seems not to be the problem. I tried from two different sources already

Comment: hm , did you try :    USA h ttps://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/

Comment: The other thing you could probably try is install RTools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then install the package .

Comment: The problem is that the developer of this package (mlr), created it for an older version of R, the 2.8 version. Actually, I'm running the 3.3.1 version.

Comment: ok , but i tried installing the mlr package and my R version is 3.2.0 and it worked for me .

Comment: @RoxanaNoelia that is incorrect. you just need need rtools installed. mlr works with the latest version of R.

Comment: I tried to install via Rtools, but i got this message:   package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1) I'm also running the last Rstudio version.

Comment: 2.8 is the current version of `mlr`, it runs solidly in R 3.3.1.